# Smallest integer $x$ such that $\gcd(d, 3x^4-2) = n > 1$ for every divisor $d > 1$ of $3x^4-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

What is the smallest $x$ such that $\gcd(d, 3x^4-2) = n > 1$ for every divisor $d > 1$ of $3x^4-1$? Search of this $x$ shows that $x > 120$. And for some $n$, this is impossible because there are no solutions to $3x^4-1 = 1 \pmod n$. This is true for $n < 19$. This makes the problem harder. Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: If $d$ divides $3x^4-1$ then it must be relatively prime to $3x^4-2$.

Comment: @lulu that is obvious did you understand the problem?

Comment: Obviously not.  It seems clear that no $x$ of your form exists.  If I am misreading, then please explain.